# "E: Unable to locate package fluxion" : This error is showing when i try to uninstall fluxion

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, git, software-uninstall

[Here is the screenshot of the command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEQHi.png)

I am using **Linux 18.04**. I used this `sudo git clone https://github.com/PNPtutorials/fluxion.git` command to colne the file. After git clone i changed the directory to `fluxion` and there is a file name `Installer.sh`. I used `sudo ./Installer.sh` command to install the softwar. But now i want to uninstall it. But when i run this `sudo apt-get remove fluxion` command it show:

- `Reading package lists... Done`
- `Building dependency tree`
- `Reading state information... Done`
- `E: Unable to locate package fluxion`

I also attach the picture of the command prompt. I have searched for the solution of this problem but could not find exact solution which is related to this fluxion software uninstall problem. As i am not well versed with deep linux knowledge,i will be grateful if anyone can give me the step for uninstalling this software.

Comment: You cannot uninstall programs via `apt-get remove` that you did not install via `apt-get`or `dpgk`. Whith the `git clone` command you did not install, but only copy the program sources. How did you install then (`make`, `make install` or the like?)

Comment: @ridgy after git clone i changed the directory to `fluxion` and there is a file name `Installer.sh`. I used `sudo ./Installer.sh` to install the software.

Comment: Just find out if there is also a file named `Uninstall.sh`; if yes, call that. Oherwise you have to find out what the installer script did and where it copied program files. Sometimes here is also a `README` or `INSTALL` text file, which can help further.

Comment: ridgy there is no such a file which name is `Uninstall.sh` and there is a `README` file which is about how fluxion works. But there is a file `remove.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Apt is the wrong tool for this job.

- Apt handles ONLY .deb packages.
- Apt has never heard of git (nor Snaps nor Flatpackage, nor Wheels, etc).
- Apt has no way to track what you may have cloned.

If the software you cloned has a README file or other documentation, consult it. Also look for an uninstall script included with the software. Finally, consult the user community (or developer) of the software for uninstall instructions.

Git cloning is a method of software *distribution*. But, as you have discovered, it's not a method of software *packaging*. If it's great software, and the license permits, consider packaging it [as a deb](http://mentors.debian.net) [or a Snap](http://snapcraft.io) so the entire community can enjoy it.